# Propane heater goes out at nite

Tags: walls, heater, propane

O have a new propane wall heater in my new shop with a new low pressure reg. The heater works well during the day but when I go out at 8 am the heater is out pilot is out also. I live at 7030 feet, I leave a window open approx 3/4in.. the temp is around 27deg at nite.

Comment: Is there possibly water in the line from the tank to the heater that may be freezing and blocking the flow of gas?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the make and model of heater. Is it vented or unvented? Your comment - I leave a window open approx 3/4in.. leads me to believe it's unvented which can be a problem at high altitude.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Has it been re-jetted for the altitude?  (I assume you probably know to do that). A volume of air only has 3/4 as much oxygen as at sea level, so it matters.

Comment: are you sure it's propane, and not butane, in the tank?

Comment: If you have a carbon monoxide detector (CO), use it to check if the heater shuts off because of CO buildup. Leave it in the room overnight and check the maximum reading next morning.